# Golang: How to capture panic and log this error to original log file?

Tags: logging, go, panic

I tried to capture panic and log the error:

```
func (s *server) SayHello(ctx context.Context, in *pb.HelloRequest) (*pb.HelloReply, error) {
    defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            glog.Errorf("Recovered from err: %v", err)
        }
    }()
    panic("TISH IS A PANIC")
    return &pb.HelloReply{Message: "Hello " + in.Name}, nil
}
```

But to my surprise, the `"Recovered from err: "` never occurs in my log file, instead, it occurs in `/var/log/messages`.

How can I log that error in my original log file?

**[Updated]**

If there is no panic, `glog.Errorf` will log correctly to its log dir; when there is panic, it just can't:

```
// this glog will log correctly, unless uncomment the panic below
glog.Errorf("This is a normal log: %v", err)  
// panic("TISH IS A PANIC")
```

Maybe this is impossible, since that's what **crash** means?

Comment: Do other glog.Errorf statements go to the right place?  glog, by default, logs to multiple files and, possibly, stderr based on config.   Also, you used Errorf without the: %v, you probably wanted:  `glog.Errorf("Recovered from err: %v", err)`

Comment: Other logs work well before panic. and there's a typo, sorry for that.

Comment: This could be something related to the glog package. I made a minimal example using the stdlib logger, and it seems to work as expected - https://play.golang.org/p/nhLSH_0rdj

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `glog.Flush()` in your deferred function. From the documentation of glog:

> Log output is buffered and written periodically using Flush. Programs
>   should call Flush before exiting to guarantee all log output is
>   written.

https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/glog